# Pandas on Spark is throwing Assertion Error when list of dictionaries is being tried as to add as a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyspark

I am using pandas on spark (spark version - 3.2.1) to scale my pandas df.
I am using it like this

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
sdf = ps.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Downloads\test1.csv",sep=',')
```

I have a list of dictionaries like this

```
tid = [{'ID_ID_dm001_ID_ID': '1', 'ID_ID_vs001_ID_ID': '1'},{'ID_ID_dm001_ID_ID': '2', 'ID_ID_vs001_ID_ID': '2'},{'ID_ID_dm001_ID_ID': '3', 'ID_ID_vs001_ID_ID': '3'},
{'ID_ID_dm001_ID_ID': '4', 'ID_ID_vs001_ID_ID': '4'},{'ID_ID_dm001_ID_ID': '5', 'ID_ID_vs001_ID_ID': '5'}]
```

I want to add this list as a separate column to my dataframe - sdf as follows:

```
sdf['TRACEID'] = tid
```

However this throws an AssertionError.
This works for pandas dataframe but not for pandas on spark df.

Any workaround here ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error stack trace?

Comment: @k88 - here is the error stack - adding in part in consecutive comments --> 
AssertionError   Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 df['CDH_TRACEID'] = tid
C:\Backup\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\pandas\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
  11813                 psdf = self.reset_index()
> 11814                 psdf[key] = ps.DataFrame(value)
  11815                 psdf = psdf.set_index(psdf.columns[: self._internal.index_level])
  11816                 psdf.index.names = self.index.names

Comment: C:\Backup\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\pandas\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
  11799                         yield (psdf._psser_for(this_label), this_label)
> 11801             psdf = align_diff_frames(assign_columns, self, value, fillna=False, how="left")
  11802         elif isinstance(value, list):
  11803             if len(self) != len(value):

Comment: C:\Backup\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\pandas\utils.py in align_diff_frames(resolve_func, this, that, fillna, how, preserve_order_column)
    421     # it adds new columns for example.
    422     if len(this_columns_to_apply) > 0 or len(that_columns_to_apply) > 0:
--> 423         psser_set, column_labels_set = zip(
    424             *resolve_func(combined, this_columns_to_apply, that_columns_to_apply)
    425         )

Comment: C:\Backup\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\pandas\frame.py in assign_columns(psdf, this_column_labels, that_column_labels)
  11789                 psdf: DataFrame, this_column_labels: List[Label], that_column_labels: List[Label]
  11790             ) -> Iterator[Tuple["Series", Label]]:
> 11791                 assert len(key) == len(that_column_labels)
  11792                 # Note that here intentionally uses `zip_longest` that combine
  11793                 # that_columns.
AssertionError: